# Template argument deduction failed

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote the following code for which template argument deduction fails :

```
template<int>
struct num {};

template<int m>
void match(num<2*m>) {
}

int main()
{
  match(num<2>());
  return 0;
}
```

I know from a gut feeling that the compiler can't deduce the correct `m`, but I want to understand the theoretical underpinnings for why it fails. Can someone elucidate?

Comment: `2*m` is a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/5740428).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are basically asking the compiler to solve the equation `2 * m == 2` for you in order to determine template argument `m` for `match`. Compiler does not solve equations during template argument deduction, regardless of how simple and unambiguous they are.

The language specification in 14.8.2.4/14 (C++03), 14.8.2.5/16 (C++11) covers your situation and has a similar example

> **14** If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type
>   *template-parameter*, the non-type *template-parameter* is used in an
>   expression in the function parameter-list, the corresponding
>   *template-argument* must always be explicitly specified or deduced
>   elsewhere because type deduction would otherwise always fail for such
>   a *template-argument*.

```
template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
template<short s> void g(A<s+1>);

void k() {
  A<1> a;
  g(a); //error: deduction fails for expression s+1
  g<0>(a); //OK
}
```

As to why it is done that way... I think it is pretty obvious that in general case the problem of solving a mathematical equation is too complicated. It can also lead to ambiguous solutions or to solutions that don't belong to the expected domain. For example, what would you expect the compiler to deduce for `match(num<3>())`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest draft here http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf or even here https://github.com/cplusplus/draft don't seem to have that subsection.  But i take your word for it :)

Comment: @keveman: I copied it from C++03. In C++11 the equivalent part is 14.8.2.5/16

Comment: We probably don't want an integer equation solver inside the compiler, but I was curious as to whether this problem is inherently "undecidable" in computer science terms, or whether the C++ language designers decided to do it for pragmatic reasons.

Comment: Like many things in math, this reduces to Gödel: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/419/is-there-any-concrete-relation-between-godels-incompleteness-theorem-the-halti -- or, in short, "is there a solution to this simple mathematical equation using a few operations" is not something a compiler can be reasonably expected to answer.