# What is a non-deduced context?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I've stumbled over *[Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504)* recently and the answers can be summed up to "It's a non-deduced context".

Specifically, the first one says it's such a thing and then redirects to the standard for "details", while the second one quotes the standard, which is cryptic to say the least.

Can someone please explain to mere mortals, like myself, what a *non-deduced context* is, when does it occur, and why does it occur?

Comment: Related: [C++, template argument can not be deduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

*Deduction* refers to the process of determining the type of a template parameter from a given argument. It applies to function templates, `auto`, and a few other cases (e.g. partial specialization). For example, consider:

```
template <typename T> void f(std::vector<T>);
```

Now if you say `f(x)`, where you declared `std::vector<int> x;`, then `T` is *deduced* as `int`, and you get the specialization `f<int>`.

In order for deduction to work, the template parameter type that is to be deduced has to appear in a deducible context. In this example, the function parameter of `f` is such a deducible context. That is, an argument in the function call expression allows us to determine what the template parameter `T` should be in order for the call expression to be valid.

However, there are also *non*-deduced contexts, where no deduction is possible. The canonical example is "a template parameter that appears to the left of a `::`:

```
template <typename> struct Foo;

template <typename T> void g(typename Foo<T>::type);
```

In this function template, the `T` in the function parameter list is in a non-deduced context. Thus you cannot say `g(x)` and deduce `T`. The reason for this is that there is no "backwards correspondence" between arbitrary types and *members* `Foo<T>::type`. For example, you could have specializations:

```
 template <> struct Foo<int>       { using type = double; };
 template <> struct Foo<char>      { using type = double; };
 template <> struct Foo<float>     { using type = bool; };
 template <> struct Foo<long>      { int type = 10; };
 template <> struct Foo<unsigned>  { };
```

If you call `g(double{})` there are two possible answers for `T`, and if you call `g(int{})` there is no answer. In general, there is no relationship between class template parameters and class members, so you cannot perform any sensible argument deduction.

---

Occasionally it is useful to inhibit argument deduction explicitly. This is for example the case for `std::forward`. Another example is when you have conversions from `Foo<U>` to `Foo<T>`, say, or other conversions (think `std::string` and `char const *`). Now suppose you have a free function:

```
template <typename T> bool binary_function(Foo<T> lhs, Foo<T> rhs);
```

If you call `binary_function(t, u)`, then the deduction may be ambiguous and thus fail. But it is reasonable to deduce only one argument and *not* deduce the other, thus permitting implicit conversions. Now an explicitly non-deduced context is needed, for example like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
bool binary_function(Foo<T> lhs, typename type_identity<Foo<T>>::type rhs)
{
    return binary_function(lhs, rhs);
}
```

(You may have experienced such deduction problems with something like `std::min(1U, 2L)`.)

Note: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is available in the standard library since C++20.

Comment: So you are referencing the second case described by the standard ("A type that is a template-id in which one or more of the template-arguments is an expression that references a template-parameter."), right? If so, can you make an example of the first one ("The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.")?

Comment: Actually, now that I read it carefully, I think it's the opposite.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Maybe something like `template <std::size_t> struct Bar; template <typename T> void(Bar<sizeof(T)>);`?

Comment: The point is this: There is a one-to-one correspondence between types `T` and template classes `Foo<T>`, so you can deduce the former from the latter. But there is *no* correspondence between types `T` and arbitrary members `Foo<T>::X`.

Comment: I feel like you could also answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242556/specialize-stdhasht-for-dependent-types).

Comment: Excellent answer & meaningful example.

Comment: @KerrekSB The purpose is to save the compiling time, right? As you said, for g(0.1) it can return ambiguous, g(1) return error, g(true) do can deduce float

Comment: @camino: no, I wouldn't say that -- it's not something technical or mechanical. There's a much more fundamental problem in principle that the mapping from name to type is not invertible, and so it doesn't make sense to take a type and ask for "the" name that defines it, because this very notion does not exist. Deduction only works for the much narrower question of "which type can be substituted into this *particular given pattern* to form a valid call", which is much more constrained, and hence meaningful.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### What is a non-deduced context?

A non-deduced context is a context where template arguments cannot be deduced.
It's not always feasible to deduce template parameters from some construct.
For example:

```cpp
template <int N>
void foo(int x = N * N); // called like foo()
```

It's obviously impossible to deduce the non-type template parameter `N` from the default argument `N * N`. Not only would the compiler have to take the square root of `N`, it's also unclear where it would get the value of `N * N` in the first place.

### List of non-deduced contexts [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)

In the following list, assume that

- `T` is some template type parameter
- `N` is some non-type template parameter

```cpp
template <typename T, int N>
```

Each heading cites and explains one bullet in [[temp.deduct.type] p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#5).

#### 1. `Foo<T>::type`

> The *[nested-name-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier)* of a type that was specified using a *[qualified-id](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:qualified-id)*.

There is no way to deduce `T` because `type` is just an alias such as `std::vector<T>::size_type`. Knowing only the `size_type` (which is `std::size_t` in this case), how could we possibly figure out `T`? We cannot, because the information isn't contained within `std::size_t`.

The most common way that developers run into this problem is by trying to deduce the container from an iterator.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(typename T::iterator it); // attempt to deduce T from an iterator

int main() {
    std::array<int> v;
    foo(v.begin()); // error, trying to deduce std::array<int> from int* (probably)
}                   // which is obviously imposssible
```

#### 2. `decltype(N)`

> The *[expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.comma#nt:expression)* of a *[decltype-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.type.decltype#nt:decltype-specifier)*.

```cpp
template <int N>
void foo(decltype(N * N - N) n);
```

The expression of `decltype` can be arbitrarily complex, and a `decltype` specifier is a type. If `N` is a non-type template parameter, how could we possibly know the value from just the type (e.g. guess `123` from `int`)?

#### 3. `Foo<0 + N>`, `int(&)[0 + N]`

> A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a subexpression references a template parameter.

It would be possible to deduce `N` from just `Foo<N>` or from an array bound, but when `N` only appears as a subexpression, it becomes generally impossible. It is theoretically possible for a simple expression such as `0 + N`, but this quickly gets out of hand for more complex expressions such as `N * N`.

#### 4. `void foo(T x = T{})`

> A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.

If we call such a function like `foo()`, then deduction would require some circular logic. The type `T` would be inferred from the default argument `T{}`, whose type is `T`, which is inferred from the default argument, ...

---

*Note: this case applies to the motivating example at the start of the answer.*

#### 5. `void foo(T* function_pointer)` with overload sets

> A function parameter for which the associated argument is an overload set ([[over.over]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.over)), and one or more of the following apply:
>
> - more than one function matches the function parameter type (resulting in an ambiguous deduction), or
> - no function matches the function parameter type, or
> - the overload set supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates.

This may not be so obvious, so I'll provide an example:

```cpp
void take(int);
void take(float);

template <typename T>
void foo(T* function_pointer) { function_pointer(0); }
// note: T(*function_pointer)(int)  would work, and T would deduce to void

int main() { foo(&take); } // error
```

Both `take(int)` and `take(float)` match the function parameter, so it's ambiguous whether `T` should deduce to `void(int)` or `void(float)`.

#### 6. `std::initializer_list` function arguments

> A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.list)) but the parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified ([[temp.deduct.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.call)).

The example in the C++ standard demonstrates this well:

> ```cpp
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3});                 // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```

Of all the bullets, this restriction is the most artificial. `{1, 2, 3}` could by considered `std::initializer_list<int>`, but it was intentionally decided not to make this deduction.

#### 7. `void foo(Ts..., int)`

> A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *[parameter-declaration-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#nt:parameter-declaration-list)*.

The template parameter pack `Ts...` cannot be deduced.
The basic issue is that if we called `foo(0)` this is ambiguous between providing `0` as an argument to the pack, or to the `int` parameter.
In function templates, this ambiguity is resolved by interpreting the parameter pack as an empty pack, which resolves some cases, but not all:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts..., int);

int main() {
    foo(0);     // OK, Ts... is an empty pack
    foo(0, 0);  // ill-formed despite being intuitively unambiguous
}
```

### Further notes

There numerous rules that need to be followed for deduction to be possible.
Not deducing from a non-deduced context is just one of them.
[[temp.deduct.type] p8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#8) lists the forms that a type must have for deduction to be possible.

Another indirect rule related to arrays is this:

```cpp
template <int N> foo(int(&)[N]); // N can be deduced from array size
template <int N> foo(int[N]);    // N cannot be deduced because arrays in parameters
                                 // are adjusted to pointers
```

#### Intentionally disabling type deduction

Sometimes developers intentionally disable deduction because they want the user of a function template to provide an argument explicitly.
This can be done with [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) in C++20, or with a user-defined version of it prior to C++20.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(std::type_identity<T>::type); // non-deduced context in function parameter
```

Comment: Regarding "2. `decltype(N)`" you say the compiler would have no way knowing the type of decltype, but for binary operators the _usual arithmetic conversions_ ([§[expr]¶11.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#1), [§[expr]¶11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#11)) are applied: "_The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result._" and with knowing that N is an lvalue of type int, the compiler should able to infer the type of decltype to int during static analysis.

Comment: @Starhowl *"you say the compiler would have no way knowing the type of decltype"* no, the type is trivial to obtain. It's obviously `int`. The problem isn't obtaining the type, the problem is deducing the value of the non-type template parameter `N` out of thin air. `decltype(N)` doesn't tell you what value `N` is. Even if you're trying to deduce a type instead of value from `decltype`, you end up with a chicken-and-egg problem where if you try deducing `T` from `decltype(T{})`, you don't know `T` without `decltype` and you don't know `decltype` without `T`, at least in the general case.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `7. void foo(Ts..., int)`?

I don't see how foo(0) would be ambiguous. I would assume that since the final parameter is specified to be an `int`, and `0` is the final parameter, it must used as the `int`, which would then mean `Ts...` would be empty.

I can understand how `void bar(Ts..., int, Us...)` would be ambiguous for something like `bar(0, 0)`, since it's not clear which `0` applies to the int. However, I don't see where the ambiguity comes in for `foo(0)`.

Comment: @JoshuaMaiche that's why the answer says *"in function templates, this ambiguity is resolved by interpreting the parameter pack as an empty pack"*. In the example with a trailing `int`, it's really just a technicality and the code is well-formed when calling `foo(0)`, but it's still considered to be a non-deduced context. However, `foo(0, 0)` would be invalid despite this being intuitively unambiguous.