# Overloading operator== With a Free Function That Takes Templated Iterators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-keyword, typename

So I am trying to create a function that compares two iterators, but I am unsure how to appropriately use the templates.
The class

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map{...}
```

The free function

```
bool operator==(const Map::Iterator &iter1, const Map::Iterator &iter2) {
return (*(iter1.ref->key) == *(iter2.ref->key)) ? true : false; }
```

I get this error

```
error: invalid use of template-name ‘cs540::Map’ without an argument list
```

Then I tried this

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
bool operator==(const Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator &iter1, const Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator &iter2) {...}
```

and I get this error

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘cs540::Map<Key_T, 
Mapped_T>::Iterator’ because ‘cs540::Map<Key_T, Mapped_T>’ is a dependent scope
```

Comment: `const typename Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator&` ... also iterators are typically passed around by value since they're expected to be lightweight

Comment: @Praetorian There are bigger problems with this code than the missing `typename`. The template parameters are both in non-deduced contexts, and that `operator==` is unusable.

Comment: Do I still use template<...> above the function?

Comment: @T.C I'm sorry I don't follow.  How is the operator== unusable.

Comment: @hootis [Non-deduced contexts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you need to tell the compiler that `Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator` is a type, by writing `typename` in front of it - i.e.,

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
bool operator==(const typename Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator &iter1,
                const typename Map<Key_T,Mapped_T>::Iterator &iter2) { ...}
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for an explanation why you need to do this.

But that's not going to work for you, either. Everything to the left of `::` is a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context); for an operator function template to be usable, the compiler must be able to deduce the template arguments from a call, but it cannot do so when the template parameters only appear in non-deduced contexts. The result is that `Key_T` and `Mapped_T` can never be deduced, and the `operator==` will never be used.

Your design appears to be something along the lines of

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map{
    class Iterator {
        // ...
    };
    // ...
};
```

The usual approach is to define a non-template `friend` `operator==` inside the `Iterator` definition, i.e.

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map{
    class Iterator {
        // ...
        friend bool operator==(Iterator iter1, Iterator iter2) {
             return /* ... */;
        }
    };
    // ...
};
```

A possible alternative approach is to make `Iterator` its own class template outside of `Map`:

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class MapIterator {
    // ...
};

template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map{
    using Iterator = MapIterator<Key_T, Mapped_T>;
};
```

and now you can write

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
bool operator==(MapIterator<Key_T, Mapped_T> iter1, MapIterator<Key_T, Mapped_T> iter2) {
     return /* ... */;
}
```

as `Key_T` and `Mapped_T` can now be deduced properly.

Comment: Thanks so much. You really cleared my understanding of typename up.  I was going to implement as a member function, but the assignment prefers to have a free function, although its seems something is off because we are required to have Iterator inside of Map which means it won't work as you stated.  I will try implementing it as a friend function.

Comment: Nice. A non-nested iterator class and passing by value are good improvements.

Comment: @Potatoswatter for what ever reason we have to pass Iterator by reference and have a nested Iterator class. :/