# Can't deduce template type

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to pass an iterator as a template parameter to a template method, but the compiler complains that:

```
error C2783: 'void Test::Assert(std::vector<T>::const_iterator)':
could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

The code that produces the error is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void Assert(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it)
        {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Test test;

    std::vector<double> myVec;

    test.Assert(myVec.cbegin());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing there is a simple way to make this work, since most of the std algorithms can deduce type from iterator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that the form you have `T` in is a **non-deduced context**:

```
template <typename T>
void Assert(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it)
```

Consider a simpler case to understand why:

```
struct A { using type = int; };
struct B { using type = int; };
struct C { using type = int; };

template <typename T>
void Assert(typename T::type it) { ... }

Assert(5);
```

What should `T` deduce as? It's impossible to determine. You'd have to explicitly provide the type... as something like `Assert<A>(5)`.

See also [What is a nondeduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/2069064)

> since most of the std algorithms can deduce type from iterator.

That's because the standard algorithms just deduce the **iterator** type, not the **container type**. For instance [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is just:

```
template <class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );
```

There is no concept of "container" here at all - it's just the iterator type that needs to be deduced. That's part of the beauty of the algorithms library.

So if what you want to do is just output the contents of the iterator, the correct function would just be:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void Assert(Iterator it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

When you call `Assert(myVec.cbegin())`, `Iterator` will get deduced as `std::vector<double>::const_iterator`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Liked the way you explained it

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithms look like this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void some_algorithm(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If they need the type of the iterator, they can use `typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`.

What they don't do is reference a container such as `vector` in any way. Not all iterators come from containers.

Comment: it would be nice to actually show it would look in this example.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename Ite>
void Assert(Ite &&it)
{
    std::cout << *std::forward<It>(it) << std::endl;
}
```

That's it - the standard library just parameterizes on the whole type of the iterator. In fact, anything that behaves like an iterator can be used (that's the main reason why iterators behave like pointers). This is called "duck typing".

What you are trying to do (restricting the function to only those types which are explicit iterators) is what C++17 concepts are about.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
 public:
    template <typename T>
    void Assert(typename T::const_iterator it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Test test;

   std::vector<double> myVec;

   test.Assert<std::vector<double> >(myVec.cbegin());

   return 0;
}
```

Try out this once.

Comment: With some values not  with empty vector

Answer (score 0):

The following code is compiled ok using clang.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void Assert(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it)
        {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test test;

    std::vector<double> myVec;

    myVec.push_back(2.0f);

    test.Assert<double>(myVec.cbegin());  // call Assert in this way.

    return 0;
}
```

The outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
2
```

The compiler's version:

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM
3.6.0svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 Thread model: posix
```