# Why can't this metametafunction's template parameter be deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following wrapper-maker metametafunction:

```
template <class ToWrap>
struct wrapper_maker
{
    template <bool>
    struct wrapper
    {
        wrapper(ToWrap& a) : a(a) { }
        ToWrap& a;
    };
};
```

I want to use it in this template function `foo`:

```
template <class ToWrap>
void foo(typename wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::template wrapper<true>& wrapped)
{
    cout << "foo" << endl;
}
```

Note: the use case is that `foo` already exists with different overloads, yet I want this particular overload to be called if the object is a `wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::wrapper<bool>` instance.

However, when I write a function that calls `foo` with such an object:

```
template <class ToWrap>
void call_foo(ToWrap& o)
{
    typedef typename wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::template wrapper<true> wrapped_t;
    wrapped_t wrapped(o);
    foo(wrapped);
}
```

Using it as so:

```
int to_wrap = 5;
call_foo(to_wrap);
```

I get this error:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void call_foo(ToWrap&) [with ToWrap = int]':
prog.cpp:32:18:   required from here
prog.cpp:27:16: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(wrapped_t&)'
     foo(wrapped);
                ^
prog.cpp:27:16: note: candidate is:
prog.cpp:17:6: note: template<class ToWrap> void foo(typename wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::wrapper<true>&)
 void foo(typename wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::template wrapper<true>& wrapped)
      ^
prog.cpp:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:27:16: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'ToWrap'
     foo(wrapped);
```

Why is that?

EDIT: Further, is there any way to define a specialization of `foo` that will get called on instances of `wrapper_maker<T>::wrapper<W>`, for any possible `T`, without having to specify either `T` or `W` at the call-site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/4326278 might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
template <class ToWrap>
void foo(typename wrapper_maker<ToWrap>::template wrapper<true>& wrapped)
```

Is a non-deduced context. Specifically, the first one in the list from [temp.deduct.type]4/5:

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced
>   contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   (5.1) — The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.

You need to explicitly pass in `ToWrap` to make that work.

Let me provide another example as to why this may be the case. Suppose we had:

```
template <typename T> struct some_fn;
template <> struct some_fn<A> { using type = int; };
template <> struct some_fn<B> { using type = int; };

template <typename T>
void foo (typename some_fn<T>::type);

foo(0); // what should T be?
```

In general, in order to implement this, the compiler would have to know every possible specialization of `some_fn` - even if there were only one for which `some_fn<T>::type` were `int`.

> Further, is there any way to define a specialization of foo that will get called on instances of `wrapper_maker<T>::wrapper<W>`, for any possible `T`, without having to specify either `T` or `W` at the call-site?

In general, no, for the same reasons articulated above. However, you can just add additional info to `wrapper`:

```
template <class ToWrap>
struct wrapper_maker
{
    template <bool b>
    struct wrapper
    {
        static constexpr bool value = b;
        using to_wrap = ToWrap;

        // etc.
    };
};

template <typename WrapperT>
void foo(WrapperT& wrapped) {
    // typename WrapperT::to_wrap is your T
    // WrappedT::value is your W
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! What about the question I edited in - is there any way to get that result?

Comment: @Claudiu If you can modify `wrapper`, yes. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm, to clarify a bit, how can I make two versions of `template <typename T> void foo(T& v)` such that the first version gets called if `T` is an instance of `wrapper_maker<A>::wrapper<B>`, and the second gets called if it isn't? So far I have [this](https://ideone.com/JJ9vUy). That is, I added a `bool is_wrapper` to `wrapper` and I do `auto foo(WrapperT& wrapped) -> decltype(WrapperT::is_wrapper, void()) {` to disable it for the unwrapped variant. But for the wrapped variant, both overloads work and I get an ambiguous overload error.

Comment: Note that I can't modify whatever `Unwrapped` types may exist - only the wrapper, as well as `foo`.

Comment: Roger that! Thanks again.