# Understanding std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Why the compiler is not able to deduce the template parameter for `std::forward`?

I mean:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct X{};

struct A{
    A( const X& ) { std::cout << "cpy ctor\n"; }
    A( X&& ) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
};

X foo() { return {}; }

template<typename T,typename Arg>
T* factory( Arg&& a )
{
    return new T(std::forward(a));
    // ----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: can't deduce template parameter
}

int main()
{
    factory<A>(foo());
}
```

I know this is a design choice (due to the `std::remove_reference` in the definition of `std::forward`) to avoid the user forget to specify the type. What I can't get is: why the way it's implemented works to prevent deduction? Why the compiler is not just deducing `forward`'s template parameter as `Arg`.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking why the design was chosen to prevent argument deduction, or why the way it's implemented works to prevent deduction?

Comment: The point of specifying the type manually is so that `forward` can decide if it should `move` `a` or not. Template argument deduction let you figure out the type of `a` but not if it should be moved or not.

Comment: @Angew The second one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::forward` is declared like so:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );
```

`typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` is a *non-deduced context*. The compiler has no way of knowing which `T` should be deduced because it doesn't understand the semantic connection between the `type` member type and a given `T`. It would need to search through all types to find a match and be able to somehow disambiguate collisions. This is unreasonable, so the standard doesn't allow it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking for. I think reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context) will do the rest.

Answer (score 9):

The reason you have to specify a type for `forward`, by design, is what happens to `a` inside the function:

```
template<typename T,typename Arg>
T* factory( Arg&& a )
{
    // 'a' is always an lvalue here
```

Since `a` is *always* an lvalue, there isn't enough information in `a` itself to be able to determine if it was passed in as an lvalue or rvalue. *That* information is only available via the type `Arg`, which will be either `X` or `X&`. Without that extra type information, it's impossible to know whether or now `a` must be forwarded as an lvalue or rvalue... which is why you need to provide it:

```
    return new T(std::forward<Arg>(a));
}
```

Comment: Well, I thought OP was asking a slightly different question. Will leave this here anyway.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It was not very clear from the question. I hope the edit helps to figure out which was my trouble.

Answer (score 0):

From C++11 standard:

> 14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id
>
> — The expression of a decltype-specifier.
>
> — A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a
>   subexpression references a template parameter.
>
> — A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function
>   parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call
>   for which argument deduction is being done.
>
> etc...

`std::forward` is declared like this:

`template<typename _Tp> 
 constexpr _Tp&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept`

According to first sentence above:
`typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type` is non deduced context.