# Can't deduce template parameter with std::enable_if as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

So, I'm following the example set by the code somewhere on this web page:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/

Here's what I have:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(const typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>& val) {
    std::cout << "fun<int>";
}

template<typename T>
void fun(const typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>& val) {
    std::cout << "fun<float>";
}

int main()
{
    fun(4);
    fun(4.4);
}
```

This way I would have to write:

```
fun<int>(4);
fun<double>(4.4);
```

How would I avoid that?

Compiler complains that it can't deduce the parameter `T`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The examples are wrong, since `T` *is* in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/3953764). Unless you call the function like `fun<int>(4);`, the code won't compile, but this is probably not what the author intended to show.

The correct usage would be to allow `T` to be deduced by the compiler, and to place a SFINAE condition elsewhere, e.g., in a return type syntax:

```
template <typename T>
auto fun(const T& val)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
{
    std::cout << "fun<int>";
}

template <typename T>
auto fun(const T& val)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type
{
    std::cout << "fun<float>";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b277a88453eaf5e)

Also, the `typename`s in your code contradict your usage of `std::enable_if_t`.

Use either [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
typename std::enable_if<...>::type
```

or [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
std::enable_if_t<...>
```

---

> *How would that work in a constructor which doesn't have a return type though?*

In case of constructors, the SFINAE condition can be hidden in a template parameter list:

```
struct A
{    
    template <typename T,
              typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    A(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "A<int>";
    }

    template <typename T,
              typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    A(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "A<float>";
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/906f19feb6571e3c)

Alternatively, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can use concepts for that:

```
A(const std::integral auto& val);

A(const std::floating_point auto& val);
```

Comment: I see. How would that work in a constructor which doesn't have a return type though?

Comment: What is the significance of using `int` as the second argument of `std::enable_if`? Is it arbitrary? Or is it because `int = 0` is safe?

Answer (score 1):

To allow deduction you need a function parameter that is straightforwardly based on `T`. You then need to figure out where to put your `enable_if` (which indeed does not allow `T` to be deduced). Common options are on the return type or on an extra default parameter that you ignore.

Some good examples here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if