# Defaulted parameter after parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

This is an extension of the standard `std::max` function, so it can take a random amount of arguments.

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename Compare = std::greater<>> constexpr
const auto max(const T& first, const U& second, Compare comp = Compare())
{
    return comp(first, second) ? first : second;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Pack, typename Compare = std::greater<>> constexpr
const auto max(const T& first, const U& second, const Pack&... rest, Compare comp = Compare())
{
    return comp(first, second) ? max(first, rest..., comp) : max(second, rest..., comp);
}
```

As I understand, the `comp` parameter will take the value of the last argument with which I call the function.

Am I wrong? What can I do about it?

```
std::cout << max(2, 3, 4, 5); //boom
std::cout << max(2, 3, 4, 5, std::greater<>()); //boom
```

Of course it works fine if I remove `comp` entirely.

Comment: `rest` is in a non-deduced context. (This is pretty much why the "variadic" version of `std::max` takes a `initializer_list`.)

Comment: Thus is impractical.  Try something else.  (I can make your code work, but it involves sfinae gymnastics and metaprogramming, and even then if you have a parameter that supports `()` and `<` it breaks).  Make the compare version have a different name and put the compare first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `rest` is a non-deduced context, so the compilation fails as no matching function for the call to `max` is found (for background information, see [What is a non-deduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/783510)):

```
example.cpp:18:18: error: no matching function for call to 'max'
    std::cout << max(2, 3, 4, 5); //boom
                 ^~~
example.cpp:5:12: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at most 3 arguments, but 4
      were provided
const auto max(const T& first, const U& second, Compare comp = Compare())
           ^
example.cpp:11:12: note: candidate function not viable: requires at most 3 arguments, but 4 were
      provided
const auto max(const T& first, const U& second, const Pack&... rest, Compare comp = Compare())
```

---

There is no easy solution to avoid that. You might consider one of the following workarounds:

1. Pass the `Compare` parameter as the first argument
2. Use `initializer_list` to pass the argument (thus, all will have the same type)

In the C++14 standard, they chose the second option:

```
template< class T, class Compare >
T max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist, Compare comp )
{
    return *std::max_element(ilist.begin(), ilist.end(), comp);
}
```

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max