# make a variadic constructor for signed and unsigned variables using enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I want to make a constructor for a class, using any integral type, but differentiate between signed and unsigned. I don't want this to be a template on the class itself. The following is not working. Visual Studio is just saying no arguments will match.

```
class Thing{
public:
    template<typename Integral>
    Thing(
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            std::is_signed<Integral>::value
            ,Integral
        >::type num
    ){
        //constructor using signed variable as input
    }
    template<typename Integral>
    Thing(
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            !std::is_signed<Integral>::value//notice this is different
            ,Integral
        >::type num
    ){
        //constructor using unsigned variable as input
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not working? What's it doing? :)

Comment: The lack of the `public` keyword says at least something about the first error I will get while trying the code above...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to move the SFINAE into the template.  If we use

```
class Thing{
public:
    template<typename Integral, typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            std::is_signed<Integral>::value
            ,Integral>::type* = nullptr> // will fail if type does not exist
    Thing(Integral i)
//        ^ use Integral type here
    {
        std::cout << "signed\n";
    }
    template<typename Integral, typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            !std::is_signed<Integral>::value//notice this is different
            ,Integral>::type* = nullptr>
    Thing(Integral i)
    {
        std::cout << "unsigned\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    Thing b(a);
    unsigned int c = 10;
    Thing d(c);
}
```

We get

```
signed
unsigned
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cd34654c848bd7b)</kbd>

I also had to make the constructors `public` as they were `private` by default.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the type appears in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/3093378), so the compiler cannot deduce it from something like `std::is_integral<Integral>::value`. Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Thing{
public:
    template<typename Integral>
    Thing(Integral num,
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            std::is_signed<Integral>::value
            ,Integral
        >::type* = nullptr
    ){
        std::cout << "signed\n";
        //constructor using signed variable as input
    }

    template<typename Integral>
    Thing(Integral num,
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<Integral>::value &&
            !std::is_same<Integral,bool>::value &&
            !std::is_signed<Integral>::value//notice this is different
            ,Integral
        >::type* = nullptr
    ){
        std::cout << "unsigned\n";
        //constructor using unsigned variable as input
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x{};
    unsigned int y{};
    Thing thing1(x);
    Thing thing2(y);
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8b46cb5f7b16b1a)

Side note: make your constructors `public` as otherwise you cannot instantiate your objects.

Comment: You sneakily avoided pointing out that OP also needed to make the ctors `public` :-)

Comment: @AndyG I forgot to mention this indeed, but made them `public` in my code ;)

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to put the `enable_if` in the template args: `template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    (std::is_integral<T>::value) &&
    (!std::is_same<T,bool>::value) &&
    (std::is_signed<T>::value), int>::type = 0>
    Thing(T _in)` but it's all the same

Comment: @AndyG I personally prefer that too, however when I wrote the answer the solution above required the least amount of editing, and Nathan already posted an answer with an alternative approach, so I'll leave mine as is.