# Trailing return types and tag dispatching

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

Experimenting with trailing return types and tag dispatching, I have written the following code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace Params
{
struct t_param1{};
struct t_param2{};
};

template<typename t_detail>
struct Select;

template<>
struct Select<Params::t_param1> {using choice = Params::t_param1;};

template<>
struct Select<Params::t_param2> {using choice = Params::t_param2;};

class Tester
{
private:
    using t_uint32 = uint32_t;
    using t_string = string;

private:
    t_uint32 m_param1;
//      t_string m_param2;

private:
    template<typename t_entity>
    void assign(const Params::t_param1&, t_entity&& entity);

    template<typename t_entity>
    void assign(const Params::t_param2&, t_entity&& entity);

    auto access(const Params::t_param1&) -> decltype(m_param1);
//      auto access(const Params::t_param2&) -> decltype(m_param2);


public:
    template<typename t_detail, typename t_entity>
    void assign(t_entity&& entity);

    template<typename t_detail>
    auto access() -> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()));
};

template<typename t_detail, typename t_entity>
void
Tester::assign(t_entity&& entity)
{
assign(typename Select<t_detail>::choice(), entity);
}


template<typename t_entity>
void
Tester::assign(const Params::t_param1&, t_entity&& entity)
{
m_param1 = entity;
cout << "Assigned m_param1 with " << entity << endl;
}

/*
template<typename t_entity>
void
Tester::assign(const Params::t_param2&, t_entity&& entity)
{
m_param2 = entity;
cout << "Assigned m_param2 with " << entity << endl;
}
*/



template<typename t_detail>
auto
Tester::access()
-> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()))
{
return(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()));
}

auto
Tester::access(const Params::t_param1&)
-> decltype(m_param1)
{
return(m_param1);
}

/*
auto
Tester::access(const Params::t_param2&)
-> decltype(m_param2)
{
return(m_param2);
}
*/

int main() {
auto tester = Tester();
tester.assign<Params::t_param1>(79);
//  tester.assign<Params::t_param2>("viziv");

auto param1 = tester.access<Params::t_param1>();
//  auto param2 = tester.access<Params::t_param2>();

cout << "Access: param1 = " << param1 << endl;
//  cout << "Access: param2 = " << param2 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

when I compile this code using Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), I get the following compilation error

```
junk1.cpp:78:9: error: out-of-line definition of 'access' does not match any declaration in 'Tester'
Tester::access()
        ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Curiously, when I uncomment the code to assign and access param2 (commented out in the above code), it compiles fine and produces the required result.

What am I doing wrong? Could anyone please explain to me why the inclusion of param2 change in compilation behaviour?

Comment: Hmm... not sure.  It seems to work if you move the problem function's definition into the class definition, but I can't explain _why_ that fixes the problem.  See http://ideone.com/1XMZrN .  ...It also seems to work if we use `decltype(auto)` as the problem function's return type, without a trailing return type, even if the definition is outside the class definition.

Comment: Is this a _minimal_ reproducer?

Comment: @PreferenceBean I think so. I only have two public members one to assign and one to access, and private functions that implements the tag dispatches.

Comment: @Justin Please correct me if I am wrong, but isn't decltype(auto) is c++14 feature? I would like it to work with c++11.

Comment: FWIW: GCC rejects the code regardless of what you have commented out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c82dbdfefe57c25e

Comment: Yes, `decltype(auto)` is C++14.  Forgot that, my bad.  Moving the definition inside the class definition (like a Java method) should still work in C++11, though, although I still can't figure out what's causing it to break when the definition and declaration are separate.  I wouldn't think it would be a problem since everything's in a single file, but it still seems to be having issues.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, I understand that. This is what I mentioned in the comments section of the now deleted answer written by Ami Tavory.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one and a half issues going on here.

The first lies in that using a trailing return type essentially creates a templated function. When you attempt to use a class' function, the class type must not be incomplete.

That is why moving the function definition for the public `access` method into the class declaration fixes it ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5506b488634bcb0)); the class is otherwise incomplete so long as the public `access` method hasn't been defined, and that method cannot be defined until the class is complete.

Note that another way to fix this would be if the private version of `access` were somehow a non-member function (e.g., a free-floating function in the surrounding scope).

The problem with that approach (half of a problem, because you're not actually trying to do this) is that, trying to call the now-free floating version of `access` requires the compiler to evaluate all possible overloads, including the public templated `access` (Thanks to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)). When that happens, `Select<t_detail>::choice` is evaluated in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context), and the actual underlying type cannot be obtained.

So, if we both moved the private `access` outside of `Tester` *and* renamed it (to something like `access2`), then we are allowed to separate the declaration and the definition of the public `access` function ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c9a5a80b229bffc))

Comment: What is still puzzling me is that an incomplete type is an incomplete type no matter what compiler you are using and should not be compiled. Right? Then why is is gcc, clang, and vc++ behaving in a very different ways?

Comment: Agreed it is strange. Pure speculation, but the implementations for training return type are pretty new, and I know that Microsoft's parser is pretty different than either gcc or clang (for now). The implementations wrt whether it works with an incomplete type or not vary just enough.