# Could not deduce template argument for overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've got a simple function called `function` for example with the following signature:

```
class Type { /* ... */ };

bool function( const Type& aValue ) { /* ... */ return true; }
```

I've got some other classes and I wanted to overload the mentioned function so that only the class derived from `Base` could use it:

```
class Base { /* ... */ };
class Derived : public Base { /* ... */ };

template < typename T >
bool function( const typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< Base, T >::value, T >::type& aValue ) { /* ... */ return true; }
```

It is working fine if I use it like this:

```
Derived object;
function< Derived >( object );
```

but if I leave the template argument I get the mentioned error (could not deduce template argument):

```
Derived object;
function( object ); // Compilation error (C2664).
```

Is there any solution where I can leave the template argument ?

*(MSVC 2012)*

Comment: Isnt T in non deduced context here: `std::is_base_of< Base, T >::value` ? See here for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context

Comment: This isn't a compiler issue. T cannot be deduced from this, and therefore no compiler will succeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By introducing a nested name specifier (`<T>::`) you inhibit template type deduction on `T`.

That said, you have to let the argument expression type to be deduced by putting the `enable_if` elsewhere, e.g., in a return type syntax:

```
template <typename T>
auto function(const T& aValue)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, bool>::type
{
    return true;
}
```

or in a template type parameter list:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type>
bool function(const T& aValue)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: With the second solution I got this error: 
`error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template` for the function definition. And this for the function call: `error C2664: 'function' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Derived' to 'const Type &'`

Comment: @p.i.g. MSVC you use doesn't support this C++11 feature

Comment: @p.i.g. use the first syntax?

Comment: Unfortunatelly that seems not a good solution when the user not uses the the return value.

Comment: @p.i.g. why do you think so ? it is substituted by `bool`