# overloading operator for a nested type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

The following code builds fine but the overloaded template operator is not invoked. Why is that? The `main()` function prints `120` instead of `x`.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
    struct bar
    {
        enum Type { x = 'x', y = 'y' };
    };
    template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, typename T::Type o) { return s << char(o); }
}

int main()
{
    foo::bar::Type t{ foo::bar::x };
    std::cout << t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will never be able to figure what the type `T` is supposed to be in order to instantiate the template (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/1277769) question for more on that).  Just do this:

```
    std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, bar::Type t){...}
```

The `enum` you declared is public to `bar` so there's no access restriction to have to worry about in this case.

Comment: The thing is in my actual code I have multiple classes with the Type enum defined in them. I want to avoid having to define operator<< for all of them.

Comment: @BlindDriver You are going to have to read up on type deduction if you want to understand why that won't work.  You will either have to write a macro to minimize the code duplication or write them out one at a time.

Comment: Yes, I've read the post you referenced and see why my code doesn't work. I was just hoping there was an alternative. But thanks very much for your help anyway!