# why qualified names are nondeduced context

Tags: c++, templates

Can any one explain me the below

a few constructs are not deduced contexts

> Qualified type names. A type name like `Q<T>::X` will never be used to
>   deduce a template parameter `T` , for example.
>
> Nontype expressions that are not just a  nontype parameter. A type
>   name like `S<I+1>` will never be used to deduce `I` , for example. Neither
>   will `T` be deduced by matching against a parameter of type
>   `int(&)[sizeof(S<T>)]` .
>
> These limitations should come as no surprise because the deduction
>   would, in general, not be unique (or even finite).

Why the `T` in `Q<T>::X` can't be deduced ? and why `int(&)[sizeof(S<T>)]` called as a Nontype expression, even it has the type parameter in it.

contents were taken from :"C++ Templates The Complete Guide"

EX(from book)

```
template <int N>
class X {
public:
   typedef int I;
   void f(int) {}
};

template<int N>
void fppm(void (X<N>::*p)(X<N>::I));

int main()
{
   fppm(&X<33>::f); // fine: N deduced to be 33
}
```

> In the function template `fppm()` , the subconstruct `X<N>::I` is a
>   nondeduced context.

**Edit**

> I've read some answers which trigger me an another other question
>
> `template<typename T> void(T p1,typename foo<T>::subtype P2)`
>
> in the above deceleration if `foo<T>` is not deduced which subtype the
>   compiler will choose for `p2`?

**EDIT2**

> i am trying to below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
template <typename T>
struct foo{
    using type=int;
    void print(type a){
        std::cout<<a<<"\n";
    }
};
template<>
struct foo<float>{
    using type=float;
    void print(type a){
            std::cout<<a<<"\n";
        }
};

template<typename T2>
void test(foo<T2> o,typename foo<T2>::type p){
    o.print(p);
}

 int main(){
     foo<float> o;
     test(o,1.2);
 }
```

It's silly but I wonder what is the type of the T2 after `test(o,1.2)`

Comment: I don't get it, can you give us an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a nondeduced context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context)

Comment: In your EDIT2 example, `T2` is deduced from the `o` argument, but is not deduced from the `p` argument.  So deduction succeeds, and then `T2=float` is substituted in everywhere, and `typename foo<float>::type` is evaluated to get `float`.

Comment: @aschepler if it is deduced from the `o` arg then `T2` should be `foo<float>` not just `float` isn't it?

Comment: No, the compiler compares parameter type `foo<T2>` with argument type `foo<float>` and figures out that in order to make them equal, `T2` must be `float`.

Comment: @aschepler  is that any terminology name for this comparison and matching that done by the compiler besides than saying it generally as a template deduction.

Comment: It's called template argument deduction, and is covered in section 14.8.2 of the Standard.

Comment: @aschepler thanks i've missed the "argument".

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
struct C
{
    using type = T;
};

template <>    // specialization
struct C<float>
{
    using type = int;   // oops
};

template <>    // another specialization
struct C<char>
{
    char type;   // type is not even a type now
};


template <typename T>
void foo( typename C<T>::type x ) {}

template <typename T>
void foo( C<T>, typename C<T>::type x ) {}

int main()
{
    // foo(3);   // there are two parameter T (int & float)
                 // that both would deduce to int for type.
                 // Which T should the compiler chose?
    foo<int>(3);   // explicitly naming the type works.
    foo<float>(3);

    foo( C<int>{}, 3);          // works
    foo( C<float>{}, 3);        // works
    // foo( C<char*>{}, 3);     // doesn't work, conflicting types
    foo( C<char*>{}, "hello");  // works
}
```

This examples should make clear why this construct is not possible. Its easy to construct ambiguities which are impossible to resolve for the compiler.

Comment: if you can't deduce the type `T` in the `foo` how you get the corresponding type.

Comment: @FallingFromBed: By explicitly specifying `T` at the call site... `foo<int>( float{} );` will work fine.

Comment: Inside main, perhaps you meant just `int{}`, `float{}`, `char{}` and not `C<int>{}` etc?

Comment: @BenVoigt    `C<int>{}` will it create a object?

Comment: Yes, I create an object instance of type `C<int>` by just appending the braces `{}`.

Comment: @AndréBergner what the compiler do in this case `template<typename T2>void test(foo<T2> o,foo<T2>::type p)` hoe you call function like this

Comment: I fixed my example, sorry. Wasn't quite correct. Now the point is clear, I hope. @FAllingFromBed: If both types fit, the compiler can deduce it. I will add an example for that.

Comment: @AndréBergner can you look my EDIT2

Comment: @AndréBergner it doesn't work  `foo( C<float>{}, 3);` thats is what i tried in my EDIT2

Comment: @FallingFromBed: Your new problem is that you are missing the keyword `typename`.  Look more carefully at the function declarations in the answer.