# Template parameter is ambiguous: could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous, template-argument-deduction, ambiguous-call

I'm doing some kind of wrapper that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class Value>
void Apply(void (T::*cb)(Value), T* obj, Value v)
{
    (obj->*cb)(v);
}

class Foo
{
public:
    void MyFunc(const int& i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    const int& GetValue()
    {
        return i_;
    }

private:
    int i_ = 14;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Apply(&Foo::MyFunc, &f, f.GetValue());
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

- `Apply`: no matching overloaded function found.
- `void Apply(void (__thiscall T::* )(Value),T *,Value)`: template parameter `Value` is ambiguous, could be `int` or `const int &`.
- `void Apply(void (__thiscall T::* )(Value),T *,Value)`: could not deduce template argument for `Value` from `const int`.

So I get it that it comes from template parameter deduction, however I fail to understand how. Why would `Value` *not* evaluate to `const int&` both times?

Comment: This example is a re-creation of the problem, but not in any way the code I'm working on *per-se*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Why it fails

Currently, the template parameter `Value` is deduced in two different places in the call to `Apply`: from the pointer to member function argument and from the last argument. From `&Foo::MyFunc`, `Value` is deduced as `int const&`. From `f.GetValue()`, `Value` is deduced as `int`. This is because reference and top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped for template deduction. Since these two deductions for the parameter `Value` differ, deduction fails - which removes `Apply()` from the overload set, and as a result we have no viable overload.

#### How to fix it

The problem is that `Value` is deduced in two different places, so let's just prevent that from happening. One way is to wrap one of the uses in a non-deduced context:

```
template <class T> struct non_deduced { using type = T; };
template <class T> using non_deduced_t = typename non_deduced<T>::type;

template<class T, class Value>
void Apply(void (T::*cb)(Value), T* obj, non_deduced_t<Value> v)
{
    (obj->*cb)(v);
}
```

The last argument, `v`, is of type `non_deduced_t<Value>` which, as the name suggests, is a non-deduced context. So during the template deduction process, `Value` is deduced as `int const&` from the pointer to member function (as before) and now we simply plug that into the type for `v`.

Alternatively, you could choose to deduce `cb` as its own template parameter. At which point `Apply()` just reduces to `std::invoke()`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I actually managed to do it using `std::decay`.

Comment: @AlexandreBourlon `decay` is a bad choice here - if `Value` is a reference type you're now going to be passing a copy of the argument into `cb` instead, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Isn't it what also happen with your solution? That what I thought at first... Right now I'm using `std::decay_t<ValueType> const&`, so the type loose reference and cv-qualifier(s) if he has it, then I force a const& on the parameter. I know it's not a direct equivalent to the type passed at the call site, but it seems good enough for my use case here. I'm still open for better suggestion though.

Comment: @AlexandreBourlon No it isn't. Consider what happens if `Value` is an non-const lvalue reference. You're going to take your argument by const lvalue reference and try that pass that through.

Comment: So I looked a little more into *non-deduced context* and found this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context. What do you think of `std::common_type` in this context?

Comment: @AlexandreBourlon `common_type_t<T>` is `decay_t<T>`, so it has the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `f.GetValue()` is an lvalue of type `const int`. When this is passed by value, template argument deduction deduces the type `int`. In general, deducing `Value` from `Value v` will **never** produce a reference or a type with top-level cv-qualification.

You'll probably want to have two separate template parameters in place of `Value` (one for the function type's argument, one for the actual argument type) and use SFINAE to disable `Apply` when `cb` isn't callable with `v` (or `static_assert` for a hard error).