# Tuple find function argument substitution fail

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples

So, I just came back to C++ after some break, I thought maybe I should write something for fun. Here I thought about function that searches through container of tuples and returns iterator if Nth element of tuple meets requirement (value or unary function).

So, here is what I have written by now:

```
template<std::size_t tupleIndex,
         template<typename...> class Container,
         template<typename...> class Tuple,
         typename... TupleArgs>
auto find(typename Container<Tuple<TupleArgs...>>::iterator it1,
          typename Container<Tuple<TupleArgs...>>::iterator it2,
          decltype(std::get<tupleIndex>(std::declval<Tuple<TupleArgs...>>())) searchedValue) {
    for(; it1 != it2; ++it1) {
        if(std::get<tupleIndex>(*it1) == searchedValue)
            break;
    }
    return it1;
}
```

But it fails on call:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<int, float, bool>;
std::vector<Tuple> vec{std::make_tuple(1, 1.5, false),
                       std::make_tuple(2, 2.5, true),
                       std::make_tuple(3, 3.5, false)};

auto iter = find<0>(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1); //error
```

The error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'find(std::vector<std::tuple<int, float, bool> >::iterator, std::vector<std::tuple<int, float, bool> >::iterator, int)'
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'template<class ...> class Container'
     auto iter = find<0>(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
                                                             ^
```

Which I find strange because it fits perfectly in signature of candidate:

```
find(typename Container<Tuple<TupleArgs ...> >::iterator, typename Container<Tuple<TupleArgs ...> >::iterator, decltype (std::get<tupleIndex>(std::declval<Tuple<TupleArgs ...> >()))
```

Why `Container` cannot be deduced in this case? I know it can be done by just templatizing iterators, but I want to be specific just in this case.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote the question, could the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typename Container<Tuple<TupleArgs...>>::iterator` is a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context#25245676). The compiler can't work out what container an iterator came from, because there's not necessarily a one-to-one mapping between the two.

As you suggest, the best option is to just have the iterator types as template parameters so that they can be deduced correctly.

Comment: Like one of my fellow programmers is used to say, 'compilers do not solve equations for types'.