# Problems overloading operator== of template sub class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, const-correctness

I've problems overloading operator==, different compiler errors using VC++(2015) and g++ 5.4.0 (--std==c++14). Here's the code (this is just an extract of a more complex situation in my real code base):

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    struct B {
        std::vector<T> _elements;

        // Internal cmp op.
        bool operator==(const B &other) {
            return _elements == other._elements;
        }
    };

    std::vector<B> _entries;
};

// External cmp op.
template<typename T>
inline bool operator==(typename const A<T>::B &l, typename const A<T>::B & r) {
    return l._elements == r._elements;
}

int main() {
    A<int>::B b0, b1;

    b0.operator==(b1);                            // a
    operator==<int>(b0, b1);                      // b
    b0 == b1;                                     // c

    std::vector<A<int>::B> v0, v1;

    std::equal(v0.begin(), v0.end(), v1.begin()); // d
    v0 == v1;                                     // e

    return 0;
}
```

I do *not* add the error messages, because I have the german version of VC++ and the g++ errors span over many lines.

VC++ gives an error on (e). I don't understand why, because vector<>::operator== seems to call std::equal internally and (d) compiles fine. Why does this fail?

g++ fails to accept my external operator==(), so totally fails to compile this short code. I have no idea how to write an external operator==() for A<T>::B that works with both compilers.

I haven't tried clang yet.

Many thanks.

Comment: "I have the german version of VC++ and the g++ errors span over many lines." English ones usually aren't that much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two errors in your program:

```
    // Internal cmp op.
    bool operator==(const B &other) const {
                                    ///// <- here
        return _elements == other._elements;
    }
```

should be a `const`  member and the keyword `const` cannot appear just behind the `typename`:

```
// External cmp op.
template<typename T>
inline bool operator==(typename A<T>::B const& lhs, typename A<T>::B const& rhs)
                                        ///// <-         here    ->  ////
{
    return lhs._elements == rhs._elements;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1FKCAnmkT02dkrDm)

Note that the placement of `const` is usually fairly liberal in C++, e.g. you can write both `const typename A<T>::B & lhs` and `typename A<T>::B const& lhs`, but the form you chose, `typename const A<T>::B & lhs` is not allowed.

Also note that you want to write either a member `operator==` or a non-member `operator==`, but never both. In your case, because `T` [**is not deducible**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context) in `typename A<T>::B`, you have to write the ugly `operator==<int>(b0, b1)` to select the non-member.

I would remove the non-member template `operator==` and add to your class template `A<T>` a non-member

```
bool operator==(const A &other) const {
    return _entries == other._entries;    
}
```

so that you can also compare objects of `A<int>`. Note that this will call the standard library `operator==` for `std::vector` which in turn will call your `operator==` for `B`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps for both problems. The const for the member version was just something I forgot in the extracted code. But I never thought that a misplaced const can create so many different errors. The g++ error messages mentioned something about const, but I didn't understand it. Now it's a bit more clear and I have to understand this in details, thanks again.

Comment: @hob-B1T you're welcome, if you find this answer OK, please use the "accept" button

Comment: The third error is that that operator template will never be used.

Comment: ...and the reason it will never be used (absent an explicit call) is that `T` isn't deducible, not that there's a member operator.