# Why is my SFINAE switch not working?

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++98

Here is an MCVE of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

// enable_if (I'm stuck with a c++98 compiler)
template<bool B, class T = void> struct enable_if {};
template<class T>                struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

// sfinae
template<typename T> const char*
f(typename enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, T>::type t) { return "sfinae"; }
template<typename T> const char*
f(T t) { return ""; }

// test
int main()
{
    std::cout << f(3) << "\n"; // returns an empty string
    std::cout << f(3.0) << "\n"; // returns an empty string
}
```

([try it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2107ba061b81c3ec))

I was expecting the call to `f(3)` to return `"sfinae"`. What am I doing wrong?

For the first version to be called, I have to manually call `f<int>(3)`. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work:

```
template <typename T>
const char* f_impl(
    typename enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, T>::type t) {
  return "sfinae";
}

template <typename T>
const char* f_impl(
    typename enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, T>::type t) {
  return "";
}

template <typename T>
const char* f(T t) {
  return f_impl<T>(t);
}
```

[**on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e183a1f5fb06773c)

---

Your original code will work if you invoke `f` as follows:

```
std::cout << f<int>(3) << "\n";
std::cout << f<double>(3.0) << "\n";
```

This happens because the first `f` *(the SFINAE one)* will never be able to deduce `T`, as it's inside a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context). This means that it will never be called unless you explicitly specify the template argument!

By adding a layer of indirection that deduced `T` and then explicitly calls `f_impl`, you can easily have both deduction and SFINAE.

---

In C++11, you don't even need SFINAE:

```
const char* f_impl(std::true_type)  { return "sfinae"; }
const char* f_impl(std::false_type) { return ""; }

template<typename T> const char* f(T t) 
{ 
    return f_impl(std::is_integral<T>{}); 
}
```