# function argument type deduction (std container e.g. vector) fails when using enable_if and SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if, type-deduction, template-templates

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. 
see https://ideone.com/WKsZSN

I am trying to create a function that exists only if its argument is a certain kind of templated class exposing a typedef for iterator.

In the non-conditional case, the function would look something like this:

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
void DoSomething(C<T,A>& val)
{
    T* pT;
    cout << "did something!\n";
}
```

in this case type-deduction works fine for this snippet:

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
DoSomething(v);
```

ok. so now I want to type -deduce my arguments and enable_if the container class exposes typedef iterator. using herb sutter gotw sfinae pattern, I created:

```
template<class T> struct supports_iteration
{ 
private:
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];
    template <class C> static yes& foo(typename C::iterator*);
    template <class C> static no& foo(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(foo<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

ok, so using this, I can now detect if iterator is exposed:

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
DoSomething(v);
cout << "vector<int> supports_iteration? " << 
    boolalpha << supports_iteration<decltype(v)>::value << "!" << endl;
```

works fine and outputs:

```
did something!
vector<int> supports_iteration? true!
```

ok, now i want to upgrade DoSomething() using enable_if like this:

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
void DoSomethingSmartly(
    typename std::enable_if<
        supports_iteration<
            C<T,A>
        >::value
    >::type& val)
{
    T* pT;
    cout << "did something smartly!\n";
}
```

but this doesn't work. I get

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:44:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘DoSomethingSmartly(std::vector&)’
  DoSomethingSmartly(v);// - fails!!
                      ^
prog.cpp:26:6: note: candidate: template class C, class T, class A> void DoSomethingSmartly(typename std::enable_if >::value>::type&)
 void DoSomethingSmartly(
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:26:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:44:22: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘template class C’
  DoSomethingSmartly(v);// - fails!!

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In your attempt, `C`, `T`, `A` are in non deducible context (In `traits<T>::type`, `T` in in a non deducible context), you might use `enable_if` on return type:

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
typename std::enable_if<supports_iteration<C<T,A>>::value>::type
DoSomethingSmartly(C<T, A>& val)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: "non-deducible context." interesting.
i'll look into that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Jarod42 has given the correct answer in his comment, but I'll add this in layman's terms:

When considering just...

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
void DoSomethingSmartly(
    typename std::enable_if<
      supports_iteration<C<T,A>>::value>::type&);
```

... the compiler can't deduce the type of C, T, A from the vector argument, because `C<T,A>` in `support_iteration<C<T,A>>::value` is in a non-deducible context.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context) explains it in more detail.

The following change would fix this:

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
    void DoSomethingSmartly(
        C<T,A>& c, //Now deducible...
        typename std::enable_if<supports_iteration<C<T,A>>::value>::type* = 0)
    {
        T* pT;
        cout << "did something smartly!\n";
    }
```

Now the first argument is used to deduce C, T, A and the second argument is used to determine whether the function is callable based on SFINAE. `* = 0` is used so that you never have to pass the additional parameter in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. what I really wanted was this (I actually didn't care about iteration, it was a bad proxy for exposing syntactic T::size() function):

```
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A, 
    typename = decltype(
        declval<C<T,A>>().size()
        ,void()
    )
>
void DoSomethingReallySmartly(C<T,A>& val)
{
    T* pT;
    cout << "did something really smartly!\n";
}
```

...but I still want to know why the type deduction failed in the original attempt!!!

Comment: In `traits<T>::type`, T in a non deducible context.