# Automatic type deduction fails with SFINAE+type traits

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

This minimal compileable sample seems like a pretty standard setup of [SFINAE](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct AType{};

// Helper type-trait templates for AType
template<typename T> struct isAType{ static const bool value = false; };
template<> struct isAType<AType>{ static const bool value = true; };

template<typename T>
void function( typename std::enable_if<isAType<T>::value, T>::type& t 
) {}

int main()
{
  AType a1;

  // This line, using automatic type deduction, fails to compile:  
  // function( a1 );

  // If you manually specify template parameter, it compiles:
  function<AType>( a1 );
}
```

The error message I get, when `function( a1 );` is uncommented, is the following:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘function(AType&)’
   function( a1 );
                ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void function(typename 
std::enable_if<isAType<T>::value, T>::type&)
 void function( typename std::enable_if<isAType<T>::value, T>::type& t ) 
{}
      ^
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:16: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
   function( a1 );
```

I've seen [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context) indicating that "T" is in a nondeduced context.  "Nondeduced context" is a new concept to me but enough ink has been spilled elsewhere that I can figure it out.  My question here, I guess, is whether my declaration of `function` can be tweaked in such a way that automatic type deduction will succeed.  Is there a canonical way to implement SFINAE with type traits such that automatic type deduction succeeds?

Comment: Change it to `template<class T>enable_if_t<isAType<T>::value>> function(T) {}`.

Comment: `template <typename T> using isAType = std::is_same<AType, T>;`.

Comment: Ah, neat, but that does require me to change the return type.

Comment: @MichaelCarilli What's the problem with that? The return type is still `void`.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, because std::enable_if<true>::type defaults to void.   This works fine:  `template<typename T>
typename enable_if<isAType<T>::value>::type
function( T t ) {}` (same as your suggestion but using enable_if directly instead of enable_if_t).  However, I can't get your version (with enable_if_t) to compile as you wrote it.  I get the following error:  `main.cpp:26:1: error: ‘enable_if_t’ does not name a type
 enable_if_t<isAType<T>::value>, T> function(T) {}
`  I am using namespace std and compiling with std=c++14.

Answer (score 1):

Not all C++ compilers support it, but if yours does this is the cleanest way to do this:

```
template<bool b>
using sfinae = typename std::enable_if< b, bool >::type;

template<class T,
  sfinae<isAType<T>::value> =true
>
void function( T& t  )
{
}
```

in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) I wouldn't bother with the `sfinae` alias, but getting rid of the `typename` makes it worth it in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Note that the `=true` portion is required, but  if it was `=false` it would mean the same thing.

What is going on here is we define a non-type template parameter whose type only exists if the test passes.  We then give it a default value.

I find this technique reads the most like the incoming [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) I mean  [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) I mean [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) Concepts feature of C++.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I guess the substitution checks can be performed using arguments, return type, or template parameters, and your answer is an example of the third approach.  There is one thing that remains surprising to me:  If I'm reading your code correctly, `sfinae<isAType<T>::value>` is a type (bool) when isAType succeeds, so your code becomes equivalent to `template<class T, bool = true>`.  I checked, and writing `template<class T, bool = true>` directly does compile.  I am surprised that the compiler allows assigning a default value to a type like that without giving it a name.

Comment: Also, is there anything wrong with the following, which also uses a second dummy template parameter with default value?  It compiles just fine:

Comment: `template<typename T
       , typename U = typename enable_if<isAType<T>::value>::type > 
void function( T t ) {}`

Comment: @michael it doesn't play nice with mutually exclusive SFINAE overloads as the default value is not part of the template signature; its existence is.

Comment: I have heard this difference described as soft error vs hard error.
The unnamed  defaulted typename is a feature specifically to support a soft error: SFINAE - "is not an error"
The named type must be resolved. It is a "proper" or "hard" error.