# Pass function pointer into Variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function printint which take an integer as parameter. How I can pass it into a variadic template as below? I have try run_callback(printint,1) but it says "no instance match with the function". Please help, thank you!

```
void printint(int i)
{

}

template <typename ...Args>
void run_callback(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func, Args ...as)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call your function template, e.g., like so

```
run_callback(printint, 1);
```

the compiler will try to deduce template arguments which, when substituted into the function parameter types, will make the function parameter types match the types of the arguments. The problem here is that there are no `Args...` that you could put into `const std::function<void(Args...)>&` to make that type match the type of `printint`, which is `void(int)`. Therefore, template argument deduction fails.

If you just want your `run_callback` to use any function with a signature that matches `Args...`, have it take a reference to a function with such signature:

```
template <typename... Args>
void run_callback(void (&func)(Args...), Args... as)
{
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A%0Avoid+printint(int+i)%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Avoid+run_callback(void+(%26func)(Args...),+Args...+as)%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++run_callback(printint,+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:65.97325408618127,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.02674591381872,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

This, however, will be somewhat brittle as it basically requires that the types in `Args` are exact matches for the parameter types of the callback. Most likely, you'd want `run_callback` to work with any function (or, more general, any callable) that could be called with the given `args`. One way to achieve this would be to have your function template accept any type as a callback but only enable the overload when the `func` parameter is actually a callable that is invocable using the respective argument list:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto run_callback(F&& f, Args&&... as) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>>
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(as)...);  // call the callback
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Avoid+printint(int+i)%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+F,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+run_callback(F%26%26+f,+Args%26%26...+as)+-%3E+std::enable_if_t%3Cstd::is_invocable_v%3CF,+Args...%3E%3E%0A%7B%0A++++f(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(as)...)%3B++//+call+the+callback%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++run_callback(printint,+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:65.97325408618127,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.02674591381872,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Finally, if, for some reason, you really absolutely need your `func` parameter the be an `std::function`, you could hide the `Args...` parameter pack in `func` in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context):

```
template <typename... Args>
void run_callback(const std::common_type_t<std::function<void(Args...)>>& func, Args... as)
{
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Avoid+printint(int+i)%0A%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Avoid+run_callback(const+std::common_type_t%3Cstd::function%3Cvoid(Args...)%3E%3E%26+func,+Args...+as)%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++run_callback(printint,+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:65.97325408618127,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.02674591381872,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

The trick here is the use of `std::common_type_t<T>`, which really is just a shorthand for `std::common_type<T>::type`, which will just come out to be `T` again in the end (Note: there's nothing special about `std::common_type` except that it's already there for us to use; we could use any other helper template; all we need is something that forwards its argument to a dependent name). It's impossible in general to unambiguously deduce which `T` you'd have to plug into `C<T>::xyz` to make `C<T>::xyz` become a certain type. It's not even guaranteed that there is such an `xyz` for every single `T` or that `C<T>::xyz` would be a type to begin with. For this reason, the *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id* is defined to be a non-deduced context [[temp.deduct.type]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.1). Long story short, that means that `Args...` now appears in the type of the parameter `func` in such a way that the compiler will not try to deduce what `Args...` should be from an argument passed for the `func` parameter (i.e., it will not try to do the thing that caused your original code to fail). It still can deduce `Args...` from the `as` function parameter pack, however. Thus, type deduction will just make `Args...` be whatever the types of the arguments passed for `as...` are and succeed. After type deduction succeeded, the deduced `Args...` are substituted back into the remaining parameters and the type of `func` will come out to be `const std::function<void(Args...)>&` but now with the types of `Args...` taken from what they were deduced to be from the `as` parameter pack.

Another way to do basically the same thing would be to, e.g., wrap the argument for the first parameter in an initializer list:

```
run_callback({ printint }, 1);
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Avoid+printint(int+i)%0A%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Avoid+run_callback(const+std::function%3Cvoid(Args...)%3E%26+func,+Args...+as)%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++run_callback(%7B+printint+%7D,+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:65.97325408618127,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.02674591381872,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

An argument that is an initializer list also makes the parameter a non-deduced context in this case [[temp.deduct.type]/5.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.6), so the explanation for why this works is basically the same as in the previous example. Note that, while the previous approach solves the problem from within the template declaration, this approach solves it at the site of the function call.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! it worked! Could you please explain for me why i can not use "const std::function<void(Args...)>& func" as my original code?

Comment: @WantToLearnCode I updated my answer with further explanations.

Comment: Dear Kenzel, Thank you very much for your detail post. Everything seems easy to understand now. :D