# Inner class of a template class friend function

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I have a templated class `A` with an inner class `B`. I want to have a friend == operator. However, the following code does not compile. It says, `couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        T b;

        template<typename T2>
        friend bool operator == (const typename A<T2>::B& b1, const typename A<T2>::B& b2);
    };

    B b;
};

template<typename T>
bool operator == (const typename A<T>::B& b1, const typename A<T>::B& b2)
{
    return b1.b == b2.b;
}

int main() {
    A<int>::B b1, b2;
    b1.b = 3;
    b2.b = 2;

    std::cout << (b1 == b2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have to have the friend version because the way one of the STL algorithms calls it results in `==` not found otherwise even if I have `bool operator == (const B& b_) { return b == b_.b; }`

What is the way to solve this?

Comment: I bet this whole problem is because of the forgotten `const` qualifier for your member `operator==`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context)'s the explanation for your question.

Comment: @LogicStuff Where to add `const`? It says it is a non-member function. I don't quite follow.

Comment: @JeJo I have to have the friend version. It works in this example but it doesn't work in my real code-base.

Comment: @Mochan, you put an assignment (=) instead of equality (==) in `bool operator ==`

Comment: @aparpara Sorry typo. I wrote that as a comment. It is not really in the code.

Comment: @JeJo Your answer was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).

Ostensibly you could have a definition like

```
template<typename AB>
bool operator == (const AB& b1, const AB& b2)
{
    return b1.b == b2.b;
}
```

but it's too broad as it catches *all* types. Yoiy can restrict it this way

```
template<typename AB>
auto operator == (const AB& b1, const AB& b2) ->
     std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<AB, typename A<decltype(b1.b)>::B>, bool>
{
    return b1.b == b2.b;
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Works great. I had never heard of non-deduced context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        T b;
    };

    friend bool operator==(const typename A<T>::B &b1, const typename A<T>::B &b2)
    {
        return b1.b == b2.b;
    }

    B b;
};

int main() {
    A<int>::B b1, b2;
    b1.b = 3;
    b2.b = 2;

    std::cout << (b1 == b2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```