# Why does replacing the type of the member `x` with `decltype(x)` in a ctor's argument list break class template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to write some kind of preprocessor monstrosity to make simple ctors.

This compiles with `g++ -std=c++17`:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo{
    T x;
    foo(T _x):x(_x){}
};
auto x=foo(3);
```

But it would be hard for the monstrosity to know the type of `x`, so I tried this:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo{
    T x;
    foo(decltype(x) _x):x(_x){}
};
auto x=foo(3);
```

Which fails (`class template argument deduction failed`). But `decltype(x)` is just `T` anyway, right? So why aren't the code samples equivalent?

Comment: This is [non deducible context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context); however since the canonical dupe doesn't explicitly explain that `decltype` introduces non-deducible context, this wouldn't qualify as a dupe, in my eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've written is kind of circular logic. Think of it like this.

The compiler sees `foo(3)`. `foo` names a class template, so it attempts to perform class template argument deduction in order to figure out what the `T` in `foo` should be.

CTAD starts off by taking all of the constructors and building template deduction guides out of them. You have one constructor, so the guide for it would have to look like:

```
template<typename T> foo(decltype(foo<T>::x) _x) -> foo<T>;
```

In order to deduce the template parameter `T` for `foo`, you would need to instantiate `foo`... with `T`. Which you *don't have yet* because figuring out what `T` is is why you built this deduction guide in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is because the C++ standard says so. `decltype` expressions cannot be deduced as a template parameter.

> 17.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type     [temp.deduct.type]
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> [...]
>
> — The expression of a decltype-specifier.

You are using C++17. If you're using `decltype` to hide some monstrosity, you'll probably need to use C++17's deduction guides, to work around it.