# C++ template class' inner class access

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I have a class like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class LL
{
    using size_t = unsigned int;

    class Node
    {
        T m_data;
        Node* m_next;

        Node(const T& data) :m_data{ data }, m_next{ nullptr }{}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& node)
        {
            out << node.m_data;
            return out;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LL& ll);

        friend class LL;
    };

    Node* m_first{ nullptr };
    size_t m_size{ 0 };

    Node* newNode(const T& data)
    {
        return new Node{ data };
    }

public:
    void push(const T& data)
    {
        Node* temp = newNode(data);
        temp->m_next = m_first;
        m_first = temp;
        ++m_size;
    }

    Node* head()
    {
        return m_first;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    ~LL()
    {
        if (m_first)
        {
            Node* trav = m_first->m_next;
            Node* foll = m_first;
            while (trav)
            {
                delete foll;
                foll = trav;
                trav = trav->m_next;
            }
            delete foll;
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LL& ll)
    {
        Node* trav = ll.m_first;
        while (trav)
        {
            out << *trav << ' ';
            trav = trav->m_next;
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

I also have a function template somewhere else below this class in the same file that tries to access `Node` and looks like this with two compiler errors:

```
template <typename T>
int getSize(LL<T>::Node* node) //C2065: node is undeclared, C3861: node is not found
{
    if (node)
    {
        return 1 + getSize(node->m_next);
    }
    return 0;
} //does not compile
```

After sometime I tried this, again with two compiler:

```
template <typename T>
int getSize(LL<T>::Node<T>* node) //C2065 like before, C7510: use of dependent template name must be prefixed with 'template'
{
    if (node)
    {
        return 1 + getSize(node->m_next);
    }
    return 0;
} //does not compile
```

After sometime again, I tried the below which compiled fine.

```
template <typename T>
int getSize(typename LL<T>::template Node<T>* node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        return 1 + getSize(node->m_next);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I tried to call this function from my driver function, I got compiler errors again:

```
int main()
{
    LL<int> ll;
    std::cout << getSize(ll.head()); //E0304, C2672 and C2783

    //E0304: no instance of the function template "getSize" matches the argument list
    //C2672: no matching overload function found
    //C2783: could not deduce template argument for 'T'
}
```

I tried everything that I possible could and couldn't sort this problem out. Could someone please explain me what is going on?
Note: All codes that I've mentioned here are in the same file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where did you put the declarations/definitions? Do you have the necessary includes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context

Comment: is it on purpose that `Node` is private?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've updated to show the entire code

Comment: sorry, mcve doesnt mean "post all the code". The information that was missing was just where are the definitions placed. Nevermind, turned out it was already enough to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSize(ll.head())` fails because of [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts); template parameter `T` can't be deduced automatically.

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> - 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

The declaration should be

```
template <typename T>
int getSize(typename LL<T>::Node* node) // using class instead of typename works for OP (MSVC)
{
    //some code
}
```

And since `Node` is not a template you don't need to use `template` keyword.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ui6RhCzitNS9r8bp)

---

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790) about why use the keyword `typename` and `template`.

Comment: But that still shouldn't work because `LL<T>::Node` is `private`?

Comment: @t.niese - It can work just fine when `Node` is private, with a bit of tweaking.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Why? Because it depends on template parameter `T`?

Comment: Because `typename LL<T>::Node` would not work due to `private` ,  but something like `template <typename T> int getSize(T* node)` and `getSize(ll.head())` to would work.

Comment: @songyuanyao - No, directly accessing the name should not be possible. But the function can still be defined to take a node pointer, for instance `template <typename T>
int getSize(decltype(std::declval<LL<T>>().head()) node)`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I got it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it's interesting that something like this works. I mean sure, the class made `Node` available by returning it, but why is it allowed to refer to the type that way, but not directly in that case. Is it just to prevent developers to do dump things and think about it, or is it a hack introduced to get around a flaw in the specs?

Comment: Still it doesn't work. I've got a C2672: no matching overload function found and a C2783: could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Comment: @t.niese - Access checks always applied to names only. For instance, in C++03 a member function could return a nested class whose name is declared private to the enclosing class. This forbade outside code from creating variables of that class, and so the proxy had to be used immediately. Then C++11 came and variable type deduction was introduced... I don't think the interaction between these features was analyzed too deeply.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa I tried it [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yVokK_) and compiles fine. What's your compiler and version?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica sure, but it is still kinda strange that this allows constructing a `Node` outside of `LL`: [wandbox.org/permlink/dMOisJtCc4t3YGrA](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dMOisJtCc4t3YGrA).

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm using MSVS and I tried compiling this with the C++14 and C++17 compilers. None worked

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa The code is valid I have no idea why your compiler doesn't compile it. (And it doesn't use any C++14 or C++17 feature.) You might upgrade the compiler.

Comment: Finally, I got it to work. I changed `int getSize(typename LL<T>::Node* node)` to `int getSize(class LL<T>::Node* node)`. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa I might be just a MSVC's issue.