# Is this auto template deduction guide is correct?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am learning about the auto template deduction guid: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction. Therefore I wanted to try this out.

I have the following nested class structure in which `MyClass` is a templated class with non template parameter, and the inner struct `MyStruct` simply have an `std::array<int, N>`.

I have `MyStruct mStruct;` as member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<size_t N>
class MyClass
{
public:
   struct MyStruct
   {
      using ArrayType = std::array<int, N>;
      ArrayType arr;
   };
   MyStruct mStruct;

   MyClass(typename MyStruct::ArrayType const& arr)
      : mStruct{ arr }
   {}
};
// deduction guid
template<size_t N>
MyClass(typename MyClass<N>::MyStruct::ArrayType)->MyClass<N>;
```

I want to achive or construct the MyClass like this

```
 MyClass myObj{ typename MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType{ 1, 2} };
```

therefore I gave the deduction guid as above.

This code was working in MSVC 2019: https://godbolt.org/z/7PzzbM

Then wanted to see the compiler out for the other GCC and Clang. But they did not accept my code: https://godbolt.org/z/M8cPKj

error:

```
source > : In function 'int main()' :
   <source> : 25 : 67 : error : class template argument deduction failed :
25 | MyClass myObj{ typename MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType{ 1, 2} };
| ^
<source>:25 : 67 : error : no matching function for call to 'MyClass(MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType)'
< source > : 15 : 4 : note : candidate : 'template<long unsigned int N> MyClass(const typename MyClass<N>::MyStruct::ArrayType&)-> MyClass<N>'
15 | MyClass(typename MyStruct::ArrayType const& arr)
| ^ ~~~~~~
<source> : 15 : 4 : note : template argument deduction / substitution failed :
<source> : 25 : 67 : note : couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
25 | MyClass myObj{ typename MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType{ 1, 2} };
| ^
<source>:5 : 7 : note : candidate : 'template<long unsigned int N> MyClass(MyClass<N>)-> MyClass<N>'
5 | class MyClass
| ^ ~~~~~~
<source> :5 : 7 : note : template argument deduction / substitution failed :
<source> : 25 : 67 : note : 'std::array<int, 2>' is not derived from 'MyClass<N>'
25 | MyClass myObj{ typename MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType{ 1, 2} };
| ^
<source>:21 : 1 : note : candidate : 'template<long unsigned int N> MyClass(typename MyClass<N>::MyStruct::ArrayType)-> MyClass<N>'
21 | MyClass(typename MyClass<N>::MyStruct::ArrayType)->MyClass<N>;
| ^ ~~~~~~
<source>:21 : 1 : note : template argument deduction / substitution failed :
<source> : 25 : 67 : note : couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
25 | MyClass myObj{ typename MyClass<2>::MyStruct::ArrayType{ 1, 2} };
| ^
ASM generation compiler returned : 1
```

- Have I done the deduction guide correctly?
- Which compiler is correct?

Really sorry, if this is a silly mistake of mine, but the compilers; shouldn't they behave correctly?

Comment: That seems an odd way to construct the object. Why have a deduction guide if you specify the argument to the constructor? Wouldn't `MyClass myObj{ { 1, 2} };` make more sense?

Comment: @cigien Yes, that was the idea: https://godbolt.org/z/5Pdvjv But I was getting error in MSVC: Then I though I need to tell the type explictly.

Comment: No, the idea is right, just the deduction guide is wrong. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Your deduction guide contains a single parameter and that one is a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context). It cannot work.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Could you elaburate that? Why MSVC was still accepting it?

Comment: MSVC is notoriously not standard compliant. As far as elaborating, I linked to an *entire* Q&A about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a deduction guide that considers the brace-initializer-list argument as an array like this:

```
template<size_t N>
MyClass(int const (&)[N]) -> MyClass<N>;
```

and then you can construct an object this way:

```
MyClass myObj{ { 1, 2} };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5EKdqa).

Comment: Yes,...this is much simpler than I thought.

Comment: It works fine with [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/n61EqP) as well.

Comment: I was still wondering, why mein was not working though. :(

Comment: See @StoryTeller's comment on your question. Everything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context.

Comment: Meaning my way, it is never will be possible? However, MSVC was accepting it even with my version.

Comment: Not as written, no. There might be a way to deduce the `N` some other way though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219570/discussion-between-lernercpp-and-cigien).