# Partial specialization C++

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Good day!

I am trying to build a template class with its several partial specializations as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct MainT {};

struct Foo {};

template <int dim>
struct Tensor {};

template <int dim>
struct Bar {
    using Sub = Tensor<dim>;
};

template<typename T, typename R>
struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A<T,R>" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, Foo> {
    A() { std::cout << "A<T,Foo>" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T, int dim>
struct A<T, Bar<dim>> {
    A() { std::cout << "A<T,Bar<dim>>" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T, int dim>
struct A<T, typename Bar<dim>::Sub> {
    A() { std::cout << "A<T,Bar<dim>::Sub>" << std::endl; }
    Tensor<dim> t;
};

int main() {
    A<MainT,double> a1; // OK
    A<MainT,Foo> a2; // OK
    A<MainT,Bar<2>> a3; // OK
    A<MainT,Bar<2>::Sub> a4; //  error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization, note: 'dim'

    return 0;
}
```

The 4th specialization fails to compile. I can not get why it does so. Could you please give a hint on where to look at to understand why it happens and possible solutions?

Comment: Short answer: `Bar<dim>::Sub` is in so-called non-deduced context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `1:1` relation between `Bar<dim>::Sub` and `dim` as there is between `Bar<dim>` and `dim`.

Consider you are a compiler.

I tell you `Bar<2>`, then you know "ah ok, they want `dim=2`". That is: Given `Bar<2>` you can deduce `dim=2`.

I tell you `Tensor<42>`, then you cannot possibly know that I actually meant the `Tensor<42>` that is aliased as `Bar<42>::Sub`. It could be that `Bar<24>::Sub`, via a specialization, is the exact same type.

More formally, as SergeyA mentions in a comment, `Bar<dim>::Sub` is a so-called non-deduced context. For details I refer you to [What is a nondeduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).

Comment: This answer would benefit from a more formal explanation.

Comment: @SergeyA indeed, I guess you dont mind if I steal from your comment ;)

Comment: sometimes I like to see how far one can get by handwaving. This answer takes it a bit far, but at least it links to something less sloppy ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 thank you for the explanation, quite clear in fact, and thanks for the link, it clarified the topic nicely :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 by all means, still away :)