# Couldn't deuce template when I use type trait like technique in argument

Tags: c++, templates

I use some type trait like techniques to wrap the pointer and reference to improve its readability. I use `ptr<T>` to represent `T*`, and `lref<T>` to represent `T&`. I wrote codes below.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ptr_impl {
  using type = T*;
};
template <typename T>
using ptr = typename ptr_impl<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct lref_impl {
  using type = T&;
};
template <typename T>
using lref = typename lref_impl<T>::type;
```

It seemed to work fine until I wrote such a function

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t CalculateArraySize(lref<T[N]>) {
  return sizeof(T) * N;
}
```

I got compiler errors when I tried to pass a parameter like this

```cpp
int arr[100];
lref<int[100]> p = arr;
CalculateArraySize(p);
```

Compiler(g++10) output err messages as below.

```
In function 'int main()':
/testcodes/test.cpp:122:23: error: no matching function for call to 'CalculateArraySize(int [100])'
  122 |   CalculateArraySize(p);
      |                       ^
/testcodes/test.cpp:115:8: note: candidate: 'template<class T, long unsigned int N> size_t CalculateArraySize(lref<T [N]>)'
  115 | size_t CalculateArraySize(lref<T[N]>) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/testcodes/test.cpp:115:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/testcodes/test.cpp:122:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
  122 |   CalculateArraySize(p);
      |                       ^
```

and I also try to overload another function without template, it works.

```cpp
size_t CalculateArraySize(lref<int[100]>) {
  return sizeof(int) * 100;
}
```

So why compiler can not deduce template parameter in such case?

Comment: I tried even `CalculateArraySize(static_cast<lref<int[100]>>(p));`. However error message alos showed `error: no matching function for call to 'CalculateArraySize(int [100])'
  128 |   CalculateArraySize(static_cast<lref<int[100]>>(p));`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lref<T>` is only an alias for a nested type `lref_impl<T>::type`, and types cannot be deduced from their nested types.

For example, if you have

```
template <typename T>
struct Identity { using type = T };
```

then the following will not be compiled:

```
template <typename T>
void f(typename Identity<T>::type t){}

void g(){f(1);}
```

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: No. Just don't try to "improve readability" this way - use raw references.