# Why this code is NOT causing redefinition error?

Tags: c++, templates, redefinition

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    Foo(std::initializer_list<T>) {}

    template <typename T>
    Foo(std::initializer_list<typename T::BarAlias>) {}
};

struct Bar
{
    using BarAlias = Bar; 
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{ Bar{} };
}
```

I believe that a compiler should produce two exactly the same constructors inside of `Foo`. Why is it even working?

Comment: Side note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Your belief is correct, either constructor does `{}`.

Comment: Here is the answer [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Comment: I see two different constructors.  One of the two (constructor #2) is MORE specialized than the other and gets selected in this case.

Comment: If it's more specialized I guess it should be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two templates with unrelated template arguments `T`s. For the second constructor to be a candidate, `T` should be deducible, at least. However, in

```
template <typename T>
Foo(std::initializer_list<typename T::BarAlias>) {}
```

`T` is in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context). As a result, this constructor will always be rejected thanks to SFINAE.

Note how your code is different from

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::initializer_list<T>);
    Foo(std::initializer_list<typename T::BarAlias>);
};
```

which for `Foo<Bar> foo{Bar{}};` will indeed produce an error that you expect.