# Boost C++17 Unusable-Partial-Specialization error

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, visual-studio-2019, clang++

I am using boost libraries (v1.77.0) to create a .dll in Windows and a .so in Android (using C++ native code and Clang 5.0 in Visual Studio 2019):
[image]

My code needs to be in C++ 17 and in Windows build it works and generates correctly the .dll (also using boost libraries), this is the configuration for Android:
[image]

But when I try to build to Android I get this error:

> class template partial specialization contains a template parameter
> that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
> [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
> C:\boost_1_77_0\boost\type_traits\detail\is_function_cxx_11.hpp   37
>
> class template partial specialization contains a template parameter
> that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
> [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
> C:\boost_1_77_0\boost\type_traits\detail\is_member_function_pointer_cxx_11.hpp    102

And a lot of errors more but they are only on these files. I think that maybe it is because the CXX 11 (ref to C++ 11?). But they work on my Windows build so what could be the problem? Is there any way to re-define the header of those boost files to avoid that problem?

Comment: There are warnings not errors BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 but they appear as an error, as the only errors that are in code. Is there any other thing I need to do to disable these warnings or see the real problem?

Comment: For your reference: [What is a nondeduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context). Do you treat warnings as errors in setting?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT no I don't treat warnings as errors in settings, also the only warnings I have are from "unkown pragma ignored" because I use some shared code with pragma regions to divide the code