# Function template overload with constraints

Tags: c++, function, templates, partial-specialization

I have the following code:

```cpp
// converters.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static TTo convert(const TFrom& from)
{
    TTo t = static_cast<TTo>(from);

    std::cout << "From type: " << typeid(TFrom).name() << "\nTo type: " << typeid(TTo).name();

    return t;
}


template<typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static int convert(std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<TFrom>, TFrom> const& from)
{
    std::cout << "[X] From type: " << typeid(TFrom).name() << "\nTo type: " << typeid(TTo).name();

    return 0;
}

// Main.cpp
#include "converters.h"

enum class Season
{
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter
};


int main()
{
    convert<int>(Season::Spring);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to add some constraints to `TFrom` or `TTo` or both as function template specialization, but somehow it's not working. The more stricter version of the function template specialization is not getting called.
In the above example, I expect the second one is getting called, however, it is still calling the primary one.
How can I add constraints to function template specialization?
What if `TTo` or `TFrom` is STL types, like `std::unordered_map<TKey, TVal>`? What I want to do is to convert from any type to the other type with this `convert` function call. If the primary template doesn't meet the need, then just add a new specialization. Anyone can give some guidance on how to achieve this purpose? Thanks. Any input is appreciated.

Note: I know some [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) concept can add constraints, but let's assume it's [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) due to some reason.

Comment: did you keep the `TTo` parameter on purpose (while return type is `int`)?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Usually I just need to specify `TTo` for the return type, regarding the `TFrom` usually it can be deduced from the parameter. All I want is to convert any one type to another type with `convert<SomeType>(SomeParam)` function call. When I add some constraints on `TTo` or `TFrom`, the most strictest version is picked.

Comment: it does matter when caller calls `convert<X>(someenum)` and expects to get a `X` but you return an `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function declaration:

```
template<typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static int convert(std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<TFrom>, TFrom> const& from);
```

type `TFrom` appears in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context). So, when you call:

```
convert<int>(Season::Spring);
```

the compiler can only call (due to SFINAE)

```
template <typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static TTo convert(const TFrom& from);
```

You may get the behavior you expect by SFINAE-ing on the return type, i.e.:

```
template <typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum_v<TFrom>, TTo> convert(TFrom const& from) {
    TTo t = static_cast<TTo>(from);
    std::cout << "From type: " << typeid(TFrom).name()
              << "\nTo type: " << typeid(TTo).name();

    return t;
}

template <typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<TFrom>, int> convert(TFrom const& from) {
    std::cout << "[X] From type: " << typeid(TFrom).name()
              << "\nTo type: " << typeid(TTo).name();

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

- You need to constrain the return type on both the function templates, otherwise `convert<int>(Season::Spring)` would result in an ambiguous overload call;
- Function templates cannot be partially specialized (even though you're not partially specializing it, anyway);
- As noted in the comments, there's no need for `typename TTo` in the second version of `convert`, if you always return `int`.

Comment: perhaps also worth mentioning that there is no partial specialization for function templates. Though this isnt partial specialization anyhow

Comment: @paolo, Thanks for your response. I tried the second version:
```
template <typename TTo, typename TFrom>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<TFrom>, int> convert(TFrom const& from) {
    std::cout << "[X] From type: " << typeid(TFrom).name()
              << "\nTo type: " << typeid(TTo).name();

    return 0;
}
```
But got `ambiguous call to overloaded function` error.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, you're right. It should call function `overload`.

Comment: @benyu You need to constrain the return type on _both_ the function implementations.