# How to understand the modification of template parameter type?

Tags: c++, types, c++-templates

I can understand the **template parameter restricion**. (Or maybe I should call this **template specification**?) For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func(vector<T> vec) { /*...*/ }
```

This means that function `func` is only available when passed a vector.

However, what I can't understand is the **template parameter modification**. For example, one possible simplified implemention of std::forward:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Here, the type of `t` has been **modified** to remove its reference.

It makes little sense to me. In my opinion, if `T` has been already deducted from the argument of `std::forward`, then it can be modified by `std::remove_reference`. But `T` it self is just one part of the type of parameter `t`.

Additionally, the form of type restriction and modification looks almost the same. I can't help myself to thinking that `T` is actually some kind of restriction of the type of `t` in the example above.

Can somebody figure out what's happening when modifing a template parameter type?

Comment: *if `T` has been already deducted from the argument of `std::forward`* - `T` can't be deduced from `t`, you should specify the template parameter `T` like `std::forward<T>(t)`, then the type of `t` is a reference to `std::remove_reference<T>::type`.

Comment: Read about [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245676/12002570). It has almost the same example as in your question.

Comment: @273K Wow, thanks. I suddenly understand why ```std::forward``` must be used with ```T``` specified. This example is not ok here.

Comment: @Jason My problem is resolved. Thanks.