# c++ address of an overloaded function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, overload-resolution, function-templates

I have the following small C++ code sample, but I can't figure out why the compiler works this way, although I have spent quite a lot of time studying cppreference. I would appreciate any explanations! [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f4nEq577e)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Tp>
struct depend_type
{
  constexpr static bool false_ = false;
};

template<typename Tp>
struct cont
{
  using x = void;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<Tp, int>);
  // if uncomment, will be complie error -> 'cont<Tp>::x' instantiated with 'void (*p)(int) = func;'
//   static_assert(depend_type<Tp>::false_); 
};

template<typename Tp>
void func(Tp)
{
}

template<typename Tp>
typename cont<Tp>::x func(Tp);

int main(int /* argc */, char * /*argv*/[])
{
//  func(1); is ambiguous call
  void (*p)(int) = func; // why is not ambiguous?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just to be sure, the question is about the second line while `func(1)` is expected to fail, right?

Comment: I expected that there shouldn't be a compilation error in both cases

Comment: `cont<Tp>::x` doesn't participate in the function type deducing in `void (*p)(int) = func;`, is non-deduced context as always when it can't be done in 1 stage. See [What is a non-deduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-non-deduced-context)

Comment: I added static_assert to make sure 'cont<Tp>::x' is instantiated - [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vfhx7eqno)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Though rather I expect the same behavior for these wallpaper cases

Comment: It does not ensure the deduced context: https://godbolt.org/z/38PMEq7Ev. It attempted to instantiate but the deducing couldn't be done in a single stage and was discarded.

Comment: @273K do you mean "substitution" rather than "deducing" ? I mean `Tp` is deduced from `func(Tp)` and then `Tp` is substituted in `typename cont<Tp>::x`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, I do, you describe this point better.

Comment: Short form: calling `func(1)` says nothing about the return type you expect from your called function (only to be thrown away, but still); your function-pointer assignment explicitly requires a function with that specific return type, and there's a template for that specific return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void (*p)(int) = func;` does overload resolution similarly to `func(1)`, with one crucial difference.

Both the call and the assignment will first lookup `func` and find the two function templates. Template argument deduction will be done on both templates `Tp = int` will be deduced for both of them.

Then `Tp` will be substituted into the templates. This is why your `static_assert(depend_type<Tp>::false_);` will fire because the compiler needs to figure out what `typename cont<Tp>::x` is in the return type of the second function.

Then the best viable function needs to be found. For overload resolution in the call (`func(1)`), neither overload is better than the other (both take an argument `int` that came from `Tp`). There is nothing else to compare these two overloads, so it is ambiguous.

But in the assignment case (`void (*p)(int) = func;`), the return type is also considered. In the first function template, `void` didn't come from a template, so it is better than the second function template, where the `void` is a dependent type. So the first function template is chosen.

This might be easier to understand with a different example:

```cpp
template<class T>
T** f() {
    std::cout << "T**\n";
    return nullptr;
}
template<class T>
T* f() {
    std::cout << "T*\n";
    return nullptr;
}
template<class T>
T f() {
    std::cout << "T\n";
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    // void** p = f<void>();  // Doesn't compile: return type doesn't participate in ranking most viable function

    // void** is a better match for T** than T* or T (it's more specialized)
    static_cast<void**(&)()>(f)();  // T**

    // void* is a better match for T* than T
    static_cast<void*(&)()>(f)();  // T*

    // T = void for the third function template is the only option
    static_cast<void(&)()>(f)();  // T
}
```

This is one of three scenarios where function return type is considered during overload resolution. The second being type conversion operator return types and the third during explicit (full) specialization.