# No matching call for function templated parameter is used

Tags: c++, templates, typename

This is a follow up to my previous question about templates: [Unable to use typedef definied in templated structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054142/unable-to-use-typedef-definied-in-templated-structure)

When building the following piece of code, the compiler doesn't find the implementation of function, and outputs the the following error.

```
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test.cpp:30:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘function(BUFFER_T<128>::FRAME_DATA)’
   30 |     function(buffer.FrameData);
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./test.cpp:20:6: note: candidate: ‘template<unsigned int BufferSize> bool function(typename BUFFER_T<BufferSize>::FRAME_DATA&)’
   20 | bool function(typename BUFFER_T<BufferSize>::FRAME_DATA& FrameBufferInput)
      |      ^~~~~~~~
./test.cpp:20:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
./test.cpp:30:13: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘BufferSize’
   30 |     function(buffer.FrameData);
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I fix this error?

```
#include <stdint.h>


template<uint32_t BufferSize>
struct BUFFER_T
{
        static constexpr uint32_t   LENGTH_FRAME_NUMBER = 4u;
        static constexpr uint32_t   LENGTH_FRAME_OFFSET = 4u;
        static constexpr uint32_t   LENGTH_FRAME_CRC    = 4u;
        static constexpr uint32_t   LENGTH_FRAME_DATA   = BufferSize - LENGTH_FRAME_NUMBER - LENGTH_FRAME_OFFSET - LENGTH_FRAME_CRC;

        typedef uint8_t             FRAME_DATA  [LENGTH_FRAME_DATA];

        FRAME_DATA                  FrameData;
};


template<uint32_t BufferSize>
bool function(typename BUFFER_T<BufferSize>::FRAME_DATA& FrameBufferInput)
{
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    BUFFER_T<128u> buffer{};

    function(buffer.FrameData);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-non-deduced-context

Comment: Following the link above, make it `template<typename FRAME_DATA>
bool function(FRAME_DATA& FrameBufferInput);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferSize` can't be deduced because it's in a [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

You could however make sure that you actually got an array of `uint8_t` as input:

```cpp
template <uint32_t LENGTH_FRAME_DATA>
bool function(uint8_t(&FrameBufferInput)[LENGTH_FRAME_DATA]) {
    // std::cout << LENGTH_FRAME_DATA << '\n';
    return true;
}
```

It will however not make sure that the array belongs to a `BUFFER_T` instance and `BufferSize` and all the member constants are unavailable.

---

If you need access to the constants and want to make sure the buffer actually belongs to a `BUFFER_T`, you could simply take a `BUFFER_T&` instead:

```cpp
template<uint32_t BufferSize>
bool function(BUFFER_T<BufferSize>& buff) {
    auto& FrameBufferInput = buff.FrameData;
    
    return true;
}
```

... and then call it with: `function(buffer);`.